# Use SSIS to connect to Office365 and pull calendar appointments into SQL

Tags: sql, ssis, calendar, odata, office365

Can anyone give me an idea how to use SSIS to connect to Office365 to pull calendar appointments into SQL?  I've tried the oData data source, but I haven't found the correct "Service Document Location".  I'm now getting authorized, but the closest I have come is using "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Calendar" which gives me the connection error "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. (System.Xml)"

I've thought about using the Office365 API Tools for .NET, but my client doesn't have Azure and those tools are still in "preview" mode and not recommended for Production.

I've also thought about building an Office Add-In to push the data from the client's Outlook into SQL.  However, we are trying to come up with a more automatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way of doing this. What you could do is create Scheduled windows tasks to export the Calendar as a CSV file and then execute the SSIS package to read this CSV file and push it to the table. Just a way I guess.